# Creating repositories for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, unit-testing, repository-pattern

I've written a web application in C#, MVC, Entity-Frame, LINQ etc... and now I want to retroactively create Unit tests for the whole project.

I understand that in order to write effective Unit Tests, I need to create repositories for the models, so that they can be mocked, and thus entity framework will be do any hits on the database.

I have 3 main models; Category, Password, UserPassword.

Categories contain categories and passwords. And passwords contain UserPasswords (which link to User accounts). So I've created 3 repositories with the basic methods such as; Create, Delete, Update etc...

However, looking at this LINQ query:

```
var selectedCategoryItem = DatabaseContext.Categories
                .Where(c => c.CategoryId == ParentCategoryId)
                .Include(c => c.SubCategories)
                .Include(c => c.Passwords)
                .Include(c => c.Passwords.Select(p => p.Creator))
                .ToList()
                .Select(c => new Category()
                {

                SubCategories = c.SubCategories
                            .Where(sub => !sub.Deleted)
                            .OrderBy(sub => sub.CategoryOrder)
                            .ToList(),                          //make sure only undeleted subcategories are returned

                Passwords = c.Passwords
                            .Where(pass => !pass.Deleted
                            && (
                            (UserPasswordList.Any(up => up.PasswordId == pass.PasswordId && up.Id == UserId))
                            || (userIsAdmin && ApplicationSettings.Default.AdminsHaveAccessToAllPasswords)
                            || pass.Creator_Id == UserId
                            )
                            )   //make sure only undeleted passwords - that the current user has acccess to - are returned
                            .OrderBy(pass => pass.PasswordOrder)
                            .ToList(),

                CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                Category_ParentID = c.Category_ParentID,
                CategoryOrder = c.CategoryOrder,
                Parent_Category = c.Parent_Category,
                Deleted = c.Deleted
                })
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

If the repositories just have basic methods like Save, Update, Delete, Insert, FindById etc.... how should I break the query up into the repositories? There's also a lot of business logic in there such as filtering for passwords that the user has access to, where should that sit?

I read something about returning IQueryable objects, so that LINQ queries can be changed in the service layer... how would that look?

Comment: Have you looked at Effort? https://effort.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write unit tests, all of that LINQ to Entities, should be behind an Interface,

e.g.

```
public interface ICategoryRepository {
    List<Category> GetCategoriesForParentId(int id);
}
```

then a class which implements that method and contains the LINQ and filtering logic.

Now in the client classes which need access to it, pass in an `ICategoryRepository` via the constructor (recommended). And for Unit Testing, pass in a mocked repository into the constructor which returns a pre-defined result set.

For testing the actual repository filtering/transforming logic, what i found best, was to use SQLite or SQL CE, and have an integration test, which loads up a pre-defined database, which is in a known state (either from a saved copy, or re-creating it each test) and have an integration tests, pointing the repository class at the SQLite or SQL CE database, rather than your real one so that is always in a known state, run the query, and check the result set.

EDIT:

Either pass in the details needed by the repository into the method, e.g.:

```
List<Category> GetCategoriesForParentIdAnduser(int id, int passwordId, int userId);
```

Or, as User is probably across the site, you could pass a

```
public interface IUserConfig {
     int PasswordId{ get; set; }
     int UserId { get; set;}
}


// Constructor for CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository 
public CategoryRepository(DbContext context, IUserConfig)  
{
   ....
}
```

then

```
public List<Category> GetCategoriesForParentId(int id){
     return _context.Categories
                .....
                Passwords = c.Passwords.Where(
                            .....
                            (UserPasswordList.Any(up => up.PasswordId == _userConfig.PasswordId 
                                                     && up.Id == _userConfig.UserId))                            
                .....
}
```

EDIT2: Just noticed the `.SingleOrDefault()`, than rather than returning `List<Category>` you would return `Category`.

Comment: What I cant understand is, lets take  List<Category> GetCategoriesForParentId - this will return a list of Categories, but I'll need to return a list of categories and passwords... so how would this be implemented using the repository pattern?

Comment: 2 repositories, with 2 calls

Comment: So, something like:

var root =new Category() { subcategories = GetCategoriesForParentId(1), password = GetPasswordsForParentId(1) };

Comment: Or you could pass in the UserDetails into that method as well, or pass in some sort of IConfig/IUserConfig to the Repositories constructor

Comment: What would UserDetails or the IConfig actually contain?

Comment: the PasswordId and UserId

Comment: more often then not, IUserConfig,, tends to be used in most other places as you usually need the users details for most actions.

Comment: Anything that can be logically bundled  together should be in its own Interface/Abstraction. first principle of SOLID, single responsibility principle

Comment: So if I pretty much just slap that whole LINQ query into GetCategoriesForParentId, that would make sense in the repository design pattern?